# How to add new or update object in cached paged result

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

How to update object in a cached paged list? When you create the object, it is returned in the paged list but after performing an update, the object returned in the paged list does not change.

**Class configuration ehCache**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class EhCacheConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(cacheManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManagerFactory() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean bean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        bean.setShared(true);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

**File ehCache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd">
    <cache name="contaCache"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="100"
           timeToLiveSeconds="3600">
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

**My service looks like this:**

```
@Service
public class ContaGerencialServiceImpl implements ContaGerencialService {
    private ContaGerencialRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ContaGerencialServiceImpl(ContaGerencialRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }


    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "contaCache", key = "#pageable.pageNumber")
    public Page<ContaGerencial> listPageable(Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Override
    @CachePut(value = "contaCache", key = "#conta.id")
    public ContaGerencial save(ContaGerencial conta) {
        return repository.save(conta);
    }

    @Override
    @CachePut(value = "contaCache", key = "#conta.id")
    public ContaGerencial update(ContaGerencial conta) {
        return repository.save(conta);
    }
}
```

**Json new object:**

```
{
  "numero":"102030",
  "nome":"Conta Gerencial 1"
}
```

**Paged list:**

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "Conta Gerencial 1",
            "numero": "102030",
            "dataCadastro": "2019-07-26T00:00:00.000-0300",
            "dataUltimaAtualizacao": "2019-07-26T00:00:00.000-0300"
        }
    ],

     ...

}
```

**Json update**

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "numero": "222",
    "nome": "Conta Gerencial"
}
```

However, the paged result in the list is the same. How to update the object on return? Thank you.

Comment: Would you also please post persistence.xml?

Comment: Hello. I'm using Spring-data. I added my ehCache configuration class. I tried the suggestion given by Aman Garg but it still didn't work. Would you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In similar way how you are caching the record using annotation `@cacheable` by `id`. On update you have to clear the cache using annotation `@CacheEvict`.

```
    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "contaCache", key = "#pageable.pageNumber")
    public Page<ContaGerencial> listPageable(Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Override
    @CachePut(value = "contaCache", key = "#conta.id")
    public ContaGerencial save(ContaGerencial conta) {
        return repository.save(conta);
    }

    @Override
    @CachePut(value = "contaCache", key = "#conta.id")
    public ContaGerencial update(ContaGerencial conta) {
        return repository.save(conta);
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "contaCache", key = "#id")
        public void evictSingleCacheValue(String id) {
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "contaCache", key = "#pageable.pageNumber")
        public void evictListPageable(Pageable pageable) {
    }
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion but it still didn't work. After updating the feature, the result is the same in the paged list. Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: i think you need to clear cache of paging method also. Let me update the code. Call evict methods are update operation to clear the cache.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the help. Got it and now it worked by following this suggestion.